# Show that the $2$-dimensional outer measure $m^\ast_2(B) =0$, when $B=\{(x,x) \mid 0 \le x \le 1 \}$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, measurable-sets

> Show that the $2$-dimensional outer measure $m^\ast_2(B) =0$, when $B=\{(x,x) \mid 0 \le x \le 1 \}$.

Here $m^\ast_2(B) = \{ \sum_{I \in \mathcal{F}} \ell(I)  \mid \text{$\mathcal{F}$ covers $B$}\}$

Set $B$ seems to form a diagonal line from $0$ to $1$. Now It seems I should construct an cover $\mathcal{F}$ for $B$ in such a way that $\sum_{I \in \mathcal{F}} \ell(I) \le \varepsilon$.

Any hints on how to approach the construction  of $\mathcal{F}$ here?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I tried to start by considering intervals $L_1 =\{(0- \varepsilon, 1+\varepsilon)\}$ and then making $L_2$ a bit smaller, but no luck...

Comment: Wait, can you state the definition of $m_2^*$ in the post? That $\ell (I)$ seems to be infer that you are thinking of intervals and length. But it shouldn't be.....

Comment: $I$ is cartesian product of two intervals say $L_1$ and $L_2 \in \Bbb R$.

Comment: Try to use more and smaller squares....

Comment: *Hint*: Cut $(-\epsilon,1+\epsilon)\times(-\epsilon,1+\epsilon)$ into smaller squares and throw away many of these smaller squares you don't need.

Comment: $$m_2(B)=\int_0^1m_1(\{x\})dx=0.$$

Comment: @user10354138 How would you approach this ”cutting” process?